# How to Jquery Ajax Post a Multiple Select

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to be able to be able to receive an array of CategoryIDs:

But I am getting null?!? Any ideas?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddChargeCategories(int[] CategoryIDs, int ChargeID)
{
    foreach (var CategoryID in CategoryIDs)
    {
        db.ChargeCategories.Add(new ChargeCategory() { CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(CategoryID), ChargeID = ChargeID });

    }
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = ChargeID });
}



<select multiple="multiple"  id="CategoriesBefore" size="@DDCategories.Count" style="width:180px;">
@foreach (var Category in DDCategories)
{
    <option value="@Category.CategoryID">@Category.Name</option>    
}
</select>

<button onclick="return AddButton()">Add</button>

<script>

function AddButton() {

alert($('#CategoriesBefore').val());

$.ajax({

    url: '@Url.Action("AddChargeCategories")',
    type: "POST",
    data: { ChargeID: $("#ChargeID").val(), CategoryIDs: $('#CategoriesBefore').val() }
});


return false;

}

</script>
```

Comment: I think `<option>` is missing a value attribute.

Comment: @RajeshDhiman you're correct...still null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like contentType was a major player here.

Based on an answer by Darin Dimitrov:

```
   <script>           
       function AddButton() {
           $.ajax({
               url: '@Url.Action("AddChargeCategories")',
               type: "POST",
               contentType: 'application/json',
               data: JSON.stringify({ ChargeID: $("#ChargeID").val(), CategoryIDs: $("#CategoriesBefore").val() })
           }).success(function () { location.reload(true); });
           return false;           
       }       
   </script>
```

Comment: yep. problem with content type. According to this article: http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/ "jQuery does not properly set the specified content-type when there is no data included. " for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202857/how-can-i-set-the-contenttype-of-a-jquery-ajax-post-so-that-asp-net-mvc-can-read